# @ViewChild {static:true} issue on dynamic element in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf.js

I have read all the Answers related to @ViewChild on StackOverFlow but still I couldn't find solution to my Problem.
here's the story..

I have one canvas element

`<canvas class="w-full h-full" #imageCanvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>`

I am acessing it by following

`@ViewChild('imageCanvas',{read: ElementRef,static: true}) imageCanvas:ElementRef;`

and i am rendering image in ngOnInit() method

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.render();
  }
  async render() {
    console.log("render")
    // use canvas to prevent img tag's auto resize
    this.imageCanvas.nativeElement.width = this.width;
    this.imageCanvas.nativeElement.height = this.height;
    console.log("inside render" ,this.payload)
    this.imageCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.payload, 0, 0);
    
  }
```

Now come's headache part
i have added (panstart) , (panend) etc event on container div which is not working if `static:true` mentioned
if i put `static:false` then those events are working but image is not rendering on canvas and i get
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

I know the reason , its because after adding `static:true` , my canvas became static content so directives like *ngIf , *ngFor or any event that changes it not gonna work. Tried setTimeout() also , didn't work.
I am drawing image on pdf where image is seperate component.

edit:
i put render() in ngAfterViewInit() ,image got rendered on canvas with static false but still events(panstart, panend) are not working.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance. Ignore Grammatical Mistakes ^-^.

Comment: have you tried using ngAfterViewInit ?

Comment: Yes i am able to view image with static false using that but still , not able to get panstart event